# How can you horizontally center an absolutely positioned element relative to the viewport when it has a positioned parent?

Tags: css

Eg. how can you get the blue child in this example to be horizontally centered relative to the [viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) (ie. in the center of the page), provided that the parent must stay the same.

Other qualifications:

1. I don't want it to be fixed.
2. Suppose that distance between the parent and the left viewport is unknown.

```css
.parent {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.child {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    child
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to make this question a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). In reality, the use case is that I have a [dropup](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#dropdowns-example) (like dropdown, expect it appears above rather than below the triggering button). I want the dropup menu to be centered.

The menu needs to be absolutely positioned, otherwise it'd get in the way of the flow of other DOM elements. And I need to position the container so that I could set `bottom: 100%;` on the menu so that it appears right above the triggering button.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible with CSS alone. If you know the position of the parent, and the width of the the parent and child, you can make it work. https://jsfiddle.net/2bnm7h5x/5/  -- but I assume this is dynamic, so you'll need javascript to get those values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In in this case you can use `position:fixed` BUT to avoid it being fixed apply a null transform to the body:

```css
body {
  transform:translate(0,0);
  min-height:150vh;
}

.parent {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.child {
  background: blue;
  position: fixed;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    child
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! One caveat is that in my actual case (as opposed to the example I provided in the OP), the child wouldn't show with `position: fixed;` unless `left` _and_ `top` (or `bottom`) was set.

Comment: @AdamZerner well, i don't know you real code but you can avoid the top propery by using translate as i did or also play with margin-top